# Select id_value from db into array checkbox and Insert multiple values from array checkbox to one column with comma separated

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, insert

I have an input array checkbox with id values. (I'm not sure if the array is working)

```
<?php $resource=mysql_query("Select * from material_rec",$con); ?>
    <?php while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
        { ?>

    <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1[]" value="<?php echo $result['id']?>" />

    <?php };?>
```

when i insert the value of my checked checkboxes. it only insert one value and doesn't insert my selected checkboxes.

How can i insert the array values from the selected checkboxes into one colum with comma separtor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
name="checkbox1[]"
```

Whereas you have

```
id="checkbox1[]"
```

Then when inserting the values in the database, you can do

```
$values = implode(",", $_POST["checkbox1"]);
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, -1 for suggesting to just implode/insert... never forget about sql injection attacks.

Comment: My bad, missed the fact that OP was still using `mysql_*`. Though there's usually some generic "Switch to PDO/MYSQLi" in the comments.

Comment: what do you mean by sql injection attacks sir Marc?

Comment: @user3117337 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For inserting values of a checkbox can also loop through the array:

```
$check=filter_var($_POST['checkbox1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

foreach($check as $value) 
  {
     $insert_table=$conn->prepare("insert into table values (?);");
     $insert_table->execute(array($value)); 
  }
```

Comment: You only need to prepare the statement once, even then you don't want to be referencing the variable directly in the query.

Comment: This is interesting and new to me,  I already do this way,  but as your comment suggests it should better prepare once.  I'm eager to kmow more about this.  Do you have a link where I can check this. And thanks,  this comment will help me to improve my queries.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168562/pdo-cost-of-calling-prepare-in-a-loop) explains it pretty well.