# Php unlimited child menu, cant fetch some parents with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, menuitem

I've found an unlimited menu function in a blog, and tried to change queries from mysql_* to PDO. Menu is rendering all childs when mysql_* query runs. But when i try to execute same function with PDO it's not rendering all menus.

DB Structure

```
id  | name      | link      |   parent_id   
-----------------------------------------
1   | Home      | p.php     |   0
2   | Portfolio | p.php     |   0
3   | Projects  | p.php     |   0
4   | Contact   | p.php     |   0
5   | Web Design| p.php     |   2
6   | Grap. Desg| p.php     |   2
.
.
.
14  | Quote     | p.php     |   6 
.
-----------------------------------------
```

With mysql_* Query;

```
<?php
$menu_html='';
function render_menu($parent_id){
    global $menu_html;
    $result=mysql_query("select * from menu_options where parent_id=$parent_id");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) return;

    if($parent_id==0)
        $menu_html.="<ul id=\"menu\">\r\n";
    else
        $menu_html.="\r\n<ul>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $menu_html.="\r\n<li><a href=\"{$row['url']}\">{$row['name']}</a>";
        render_menu($row['id']);
        $menu_html.="</li>";
    }
    $menu_html.="\r\n</ul>";
    return $menu_html;
}
echo render_menu(0);
?>
```

Result

```
-Home
-Portfolio
 --Web Design
 --Graphic Design
    -- Quote <- CORRECT RENDER
 --Logo Design
 --Blog Design
-Projects
 --Project1
 --Projects
 --Project2
 --Project3
 --Project4
-Contact
 --Support
 --General Inquiry
```

But when we try with PDO;

```
<?php
$menuHtml='';
function createMenu($parentId){
    global $menuHtml;
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu_options WHERE `parent_id` = ?');
    $query->bindParam(1, $parentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
    if ($rowCount == 0) return;
    if ($parentId == 0)
        $menuHtml.="<ul id=\"menu\">\r\n";
    else
    $menuHtml.='<ul>';
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $menuHtml.='<li><a href="'.$row->url.'">'.$row->name.'</a>';
        createMenu($row->id);
        $menuHtml.='</li>';
    }   
$menuHtml.='</ul>';
return $menuHtml;
}
echo createMenu(0);
?>
```

Result;

```
-Portfolio
 --Graphic Design
 --Logo Design
 --Blog Design
-Projects
 --Project2
 --Project3
 --Project4
-Contact
--General Inquiry
```

some of parent_id = 0 are not rendered and lots of menu is not rendering.
What am i missing? What is wrong with my PDO query?
Any help will greatly appricated.

Comment: Shouldnt prepare be outside the loop? What's the point of preparing the same thing n times, prepare once and then fill it in n times.

Comment: Can you please more specific?

Comment: Why is the function returning the global variable `$menuHtml`?

Comment: To create child menus. What should i do?

Comment: Put your `$query = $db->prepare....` outside the function, make it global and then bind the param on each run of the function

Comment: it's that an unused part ? `$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: @rcro yes i'm editing question sorry :)

Comment: So are you running the Original code, or the code you have now changed it to ??? If its the new code, are you still missing the first entry of every submenu?

Comment: @RiggsFolly With your answer i changed my code :) now it's working thank you so much.

Comment: Just so this question makes sence for anybody finding it, you could add back the error. Or this whole question make no sence at all.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok. I'will edit with <h1>Edited</h1> :) and will write working code at the bottom of the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear you have added a line just before you get the row count. This is fetching the first result row and then you do nothing with it??

Try removing the line marked with --->

```
<?php
$menuHtml='';
function createMenu($parentId){
    global $menuHtml;
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu_options WHERE `parent_id` = ?');
    $query->bindParam(1, $parentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
--->    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
    if ($rowCount == 0) return;
    if ($parentId == 0)
        $menuHtml.="<ul id=\"menu\">\r\n";
    else
    $menuHtml.='<ul>';
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $menuHtml.='<li><a href="'.$row->url.'">'.$row->name.'</a>';
        createMenu($row->id);
        $menuHtml.='</li>';
    }   
$menuHtml.='</ul>';
return $menuHtml;
}
echo createMenu(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trashing each first child of your parent with this line:

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Get rid of it and it will work fine

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is correct like RiggsFolly. I'm upvoting yours too.

Comment: btw, you mean must i execute my query out of my function and call menus inside function?

Comment: i tried `$query = $db->prepare...` outside of the function  unfortunately, it's rendering only HOME.

Comment: Check this out: [PDO: Cost of Calling prepare() in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168562/pdo-cost-of-calling-prepare-in-a-loop)
 and this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#114616